# QuickFIX logon trouble: multiple rapid fire logon attempts being sent

Tags: python, quickfix

QuickFIX logon trouble: (using QuickFIX, with FIX 4.4 in Python 2.7)

Once I do `initiator.start()` a connection is made, and logon message is sent. However, I don't ever see the ACK and session status message that the broker is sending back (all the overloaded Application methods are just supposed to print out what they receive).

QuickFIX immediately re-tries the logon (according to the broker log files), and the same thing happens, but according to the server, I am already logged in.

QuickFIX then issues a Logout command, which the server complies with.

I have tried enter Timeout values in the settings file, but to no avail. (Do I need to explicitly reference these values in the code to have the utilized, or will the engine see them and act accordingly automatically?)

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Check if your broker is sending you any logon acknowledgement message or not ? There are methods fromAdmin/toAdmin in C++, check its relevant counterparty in Python, and try printing out all your messages there, not in any message handlers. If possible dump a copy of your FIX message here or check it yourself. You might get a pointer on what maybe wrong.

Comment: Thanks @dumbcoder. My broker was able to see my logon attempts and said that they respond with Ack and status messages, but I never see those (I have print messages in all the overloaded quickfix functions to show incoming messages) , and quickfix doesnt seem to respond to them either because it immediately sends another logon attempt, followed by a logout message

Comment: What are the values for your LogonTimeout in your config. Try setting it to a higher number, you don't need to explicitly use them in your message. It is done by QuickFIX for you. And do you receive any sorts of message at all from the broker ? And is your HeartBtInt set, mayn't be an issue but try setting it.

Comment: @DumbCoder, thanks for the help. Once in a rare while I will get a "BAD Password on Logon", so I CAN receive messages. The support guy says that may happen if their server side times-out in a database operation. Normally, according to the broker's records I get logged in just fine, I just never see any confirmation.

I did mess with the timeout values, but it does't change anything. I guess this makes sense because, according to my broker, nothing is timing out.

Comment: @DumbCoder - Solved!

I think there was something wrong with my datadictionary (FIX44.xml) file. I had seen a problem in it before, but thought I fixed it. I got a new copy online and dropped it in and now everything seems to be working.
Maybe the bad dictionary was not letting FIX accept the logon response?

Comment: @gearhead - Put your comment's content in an answer and then mark it as accepted, so that StackOverflow will treat this Q as unanswered.  Glad you were able to solve it!  I left some related advice in an answer; I think it's related to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I think there was something wrong with my datadictionary (FIX44.xml) file. I had seen a problem in it before, but thought I fixed it. I got a new copy online and dropped it in and now everything seems to be working. Maybe the bad dictionary was not letting FIX accept the logon response?

Comment: Nearly 6 years later, this answer did not solve my issue, but it pointed me to check the data dictionary configs and voila, setting `UseDataDictionary=N` did the trick. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you do not have message logs enabled.  If your app rejects messages below the application level (such as if the seq no is wrong, or the message is malformed), then it'll be rejected before your custom message handlers even see it.

If you are starting your Initiator with a ScreenLogStore, change it to a FileLogStore.  This will create a log file that will contain every message sent and received on the session, valid or not.  Dollars to donuts you'll see your Logon acks in there as well as some Transport-layer rejections.